# Python word length count from a text file

Tags: python

I am working on a project.  I have been able to do everything asked for as far as total line count, separated and sorted, and total letter count. The issue I am having is listing the length of each individual word.  Example: the: 3, it: 2, and etc...  I am not trying to find how many times it appears in the text file.

```
i=open("words.txt").read().splitlines()

f= len(open("words.txt").readlines())

t= sorted (i)

e= "\n".join(t)

g= sum(len(e) for e in (i))
```

Any Help on how to put the word length for each word is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I am not trying to find how many times it appears in the text file." - You should change your title then.

Comment: You should use more descriptive variable names.

Comment: Assuming a word is a space-delimited series of characters... strings in Python can be split on spaces using `.split()` and their length can be obtained using `len`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for:

```
string = open('file.txt').read()

for word in string.split():
    print len(word)
```

Comment: Consider using `for line in open('file.txt'):`. `file.read()` will load whole file into memory, whilst the iterator will be much more memory-efficient.

Comment: I know, just trying to keep it simple. :)

Answer (score 0):

This assumes each line has numerous words, split by a space.

```
with open('words.txt') as my_file:
    words = []
    for line in my_file:
        words.extend(line.split())
print {w: len(w) for w in words)}
```

Alternatively:

```
with open('words.txt') as my_file:
    print {w: len(w) for w in words.split() for words in line for line in my_file}
```

Comment: You can iterate a file directly, no need to call `readlines()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's optimal, but this should be working if each word is separated by a space:

```
i=open("words.txt").read().splitlines()

[[len(k) for k in j.split(' ')] for j in i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
>>> with open('/usr/share/dict/words','r') as f:
...    print(max(f,key=len))
... 
formaldehydesulphoxylate
```

Then just take the length of that:

```
>>> with open('/usr/share/dict/words','r') as f:
...    longest=max(f,key=len)
... 
>>> print(len(longest))
25
```